# Precise rules for MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

We recently picked up MTG to try out. It is fun but the rules are quite vague. It is not clear whether a player can attack more than once (with different cards) in a turn. It isn't clear how tap abilities of cards related to attacking (if one attacks does one also get the tap ability - if so can it be used without attacking, and can it be used if not ones own turn). It isn't clear when a card says "for each creature under your control" whether that count includes creature tokens (which are "creatures" but are often treated separately in the text of cards). Does life link only count damage to the other player or all damage to any creature? The list goes on.

Is there a more precise version of the general rules for MTG?

Comment: Which rules are you looking at right now? The Basic Rules? The one-page folding insert in the intro pack?

Comment: Also, did you in fact start with intro packs? If you dive straight into "expert" expansions you are indeed going to run into more things you need specific rules for.

Comment: @John, have you been reading random links from Google by searching for "mtg tutorial"?

Comment: No, we bought a box of MTG cards. It is a common starter type box. It came with a fold out set of rules. They were incredibly vague. It was what came with the game, so to speak.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> It is fun but the rules are quite vague.

What have you been reading?

MTG has the most precise [rules](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules) of any complex game. These are found in the Comprehensive Rules.

The Comprehensive Rules are far more detailed than what you need, though. You should start with the Basic Rules. These are still far from vague.

> It is not clear whether a player can attack more than once (with different cards) in a turn.

You only have one combat phase per turn, but you can declare any number of attackers.

*Declare attackers step: You decide which, if any, of your untapped creatures will attack
and which player or planeswalker they will attack. Then they do
so. This taps the attacking creatures. Players can then cast instants
and activate abilities.*

> It isn't clear how tap abilities of cards related to attacking (if one attacks does one also get the tap ability - if so can it be used without attacking, and can it be used if not ones own turn).

Attacking taps the creature.

Activating some abilities requires tapping the creature.

Unless there's an ability that says "Whenever [something] is tapped", tapping doesn't cause anything to happen.

An applicable metaphor is: You can't pay for two things using the same dollar.

> It isn't clear when a card says "for each creature under your control" whether that count includes creature tokens (which are "creatures" but are often treated separately in the text of cards).

Creature tokens are creatures.

"Creature" not followed by "spell" or "card" means "creature permanent". A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. So a creature is a creature card or token on the battlefield.

An applicable metaphor is: A square building is square. A square building is a building.

> Does life link only count damage to the other player or all damage to any creature?

It doesn't matter to what the damage is dealt.

*Lifelink: A keyword ability seen on permanents. Damage dealt by a
permanent with lifelink causes that permanent’s controller to
gain that much life, in addition to behaving like normal damage.*

Comment: To clarify the attacking phase ("can a player attack more than once...") - you only get one attack phase, but you can attack with as many creatures as you wish and they can each target different opponents.  Unless some other ability modifies this, those creatures remain tapped until the beginning of your next turn - they cannot take any further action.  Obviously, you can reserve creatures to block attacks - if you have no untapped creatures when your opponent attacks, you can't block and *you* take the damage.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, Attacking creatures don't target. s/they can each target/they can each attack/

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, Tapped creatures can "take actions". Being tapped simply prevents that creature from attacking and it prevents its abilities with {T} in their cost from being activated. Abilities without {T} in their cost can still be activated, and static and triggered ability continue to function.

Comment: (Thanks, StackExchange, for the short edit window... :|  )  Yeah, I should say, can't take any action that requires tapping, since it is already tapped.

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan, It's a pretty blanket statement that I would not recommend making, especially when there _are_ a handful of vague corner cases in the CR (they get fixed up when possible, of course, but they exist). The CR is certainly _very precise_, but claiming it to be the "most precise" is an impressive declaration.

Comment: @Brian S, What does missing an odd corner case have to do with preciseness?!

Comment: @ikegami, I'm not saying there are missing corner cases (although there are probably those, too), I'm saying there are corner case interactions which result in vague rules in the CR -- thus, imprecise. In my experience, when such an interaction is found, a message is posted to the judges list, which gets an [O] ruling, which is then incorporated into the next CR update. Even without extant examples on-hand, though, an absolute claim such as "most precise" is dangerous to make.

Comment: @Brian S, Re "absolute claim such as 'most precise' is dangerous to make". Poppycock. You don't seem to know the definition of danger. Or of "missing" for that matter. If something should be there (as evidenced by its addition after the [O] ruling) and it's not, it's missing.

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to look at the [MTG rules page](http://www.wizards.com/magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=magic/rules).

It includes the following resources:

- The Basic Rules: the most important game rules laid out as an introductory test. This text will cover the kinds of situations you've mentioned in your question.
- The Comprehensive Rules: *the* rules, in their most precise, complete, and authoritative expression. These are not designed to teach you the game; you will probably not be able to figure it out by sitting down and trying to read the comp rules straight through.
- [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx): a database of cards, including clarifications and rulings for individual cards. If you can't understand how to do what's written on the card, looking up the rulings on Gatherer will often tell you the answer.

Comment: As someone who only started recently: I _strongly recommend_ only worrying about the Basic Rules, and reading them well. The Comprehensive Rules are _far more_ than you need to worry about at the beginning (or possibly forever), and are for the most part just going to be very confusing.